# Where MapFragment using api key

Tags: android, google-maps, supportmapfragment

Im searching for a way to change my maps api key programmatically . 
Currently mapfragment uses google_maps_api.xml
Which I cannot change it or use two api key in same project . I was wondering to find source code where mapfragment get api key and change it to my needs .

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Comment: its not possible

Comment: @SaranSankaran can you tell me why it’s impossible? In JavaScript we can do such thing which is i use for direction

Comment: @RaviVarma why it’s possible with JavaScript but not in android ? Its not the api restricted but the support lib which don’t allow you to use different apis

Comment: You can't use more than one Google Map API key in one build, as it needs to be referenced in the manifest.  What is set up by default with `google_maps_api.xml` is a separation of debug and release, so that you can use a different key for each.  You can also specify different build flavors using Gradle, and define a different `google_maps_api.xml` with a different API key for each flavor.

Comment: @DanielNugent i know that and i know the api can be used in different packages that’s why I’m searching for a way to make mapfragment use different api key which is map lib don’t allow but it’s obvious that map fragment gets the string from manifest and value in string , i can’t find that line .

Answer (score 0):

You should your API key to your package id, so it's only allowed for that app to use the key.

You can create a non-restricted API key that just works with any package id, maybe to be used for development with multiple flavours of your application with different package IDs.

I can't think of a reason why you would want to use multiple API keys for the same package.

Comment: That’s not gonna work for me . There is a line of code that gets the api key from xml string . I opened mapfragment source code but I didn’t find it